# Copy and paste a tuple in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Client model in Django, and I would like to create a new Client from an existing one, with all fields which have the same value. Like a copy/paste, in fact.
How can I implement this function in the Django admin interface ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your `admin.py`:

```
save_as = True
```

It will create a new button called `Save as new` if you go and edit that particular object enabling you to create a copy.

One example is as follows:

```
class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('line1', 'line2',)
    save_as = True
```

Comment: Did you find it in the official documentation ?